# How do we play a wiggling line with multiple notes on the piano?

Tags: piano, arpeggios

I saw a wiggling line with three notes for a song for piano, and played it and recorded it on GarageBand and edited it on the picture on the right:

[image: trill represented on a staff, and on a GarageBand piano roll]

I waited about a quarter of a beat to play the second note and another quarter beat to play the third note. And let them all play to the end of that single beat. Alternatively, they can be played so that they all have the same duration (so the lines on GarageBand should all have the same length).  How should it be played?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an arpeggio.  You "roll" the notes like you did.  Usually you start with the bottom note and work your way up.  The exact timing is not precisely indicated, so it's not as specific as you suggested.  The notes get released all together, so technically only the first note played will gets its full value.

In terms of rhythm, the first note gets played exactly *on* the indicated beat.

Also, although it's most obvious to play the bottom note first, there are arpeggios played from the top down.   They are less common.

Think of it as the pianos way of copying how a guitar player might slowly strum a chord.

Comment: yes, later on I saw some arpeggio played with one hand, and the last note has to be played with the pinky and with the thumb leaving the keyboard... so I guess in that case, the first note cannot be played for the full duration

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an arpeggio, normally played with the notes staggered from lowest to highest, unless the wiggly line has an arrowhead at the bottom, when it's top to bottom.

Depending on the style, it can be played as you did, starting on the beat with the first note, and making it all last till the end of that note, or, it could be played so the last note gets played as the beat starts. Sometimes it's marked, sometimes it's down to the player's discretion. Even the speed of execution is open to interpretation. Nuggethead's scenario of a guitarist strumming slowly is a good one.